# Display a subject using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

My goal is to ask a question to the user by using argparse(CLI) and then store the input as a string in a similar way as the following:

```
marker = input("Name of marker: ")
Location = input("Name of location: ")
```

I am not sure how to do this but here is what I currently have:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Collect Information')
parser.add_argument('marker', help = 'Name of marker')
parser.add_argument('location', help = 'Name of location')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Have you run this script with various comandline values?  Use `print(args)` to see what the parser has parsed.

Comment: `argparse` isn't intended for interactive input.  It parses the input provided on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have is fine; you just need to know where to look to get the arguments.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Collect Information')
parser.add_argument('marker', help='Name of marker')
parser.add_argument('location', help='Name of location')
args = parser.parse_args()

print("Your marker is {}".format(args.marker))
print("Its location is {}".format(args.location))
```

Typically, the return value of `parse_args` has an attribute for each argument, whose name is taken from the name of the argument.

Comment: thanks but I was looking for a way to display the question first. For example, it would ask: name of marker. Then the user would type in the response.

Comment: Yeah, if that's what you want, then use `input`; you don't need `argparse`.

Answer (score 0):

When calling your script like this `python script.py marker value` you can access that `value` in your script by calling `location = args.marker`

Answer (score 0):

If you're really sure you want to do this sort of thing using `argparse`, then you already have most of it:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Collect Information')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--marker', dest='marker', type=str, help = 'Name of marker', required=True)  # The required argument is optional here and defaults to False
parser.add_argument('-l', '--location', dest='location', type=str, help = 'Name of location', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

marker = args.marker
location = args.location
```

However, note that the `help` message will only be displayed if the user types the command: `python name_of_your_script.py --help`.